# Argument of type 'ZodLiteral<number>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [ZodTypeAny, ZodTypeAny, ...ZodTypeAny[]]'

Tags: typescript, zod

For the code bellow:

```
  const mapping: Record<number, string> = { 0: 'walking', 1: 'jogging', 2: 'running' } as const

  const modelOutput = modelOutputSchema.parse(
    z
      .array(z.union(Object.keys(mapping).map((value) => z.literal(parseInt(value))))) // THIS LINE
      .parse(JSON.parse(data))
      .map((el, index) => ({
        timestamp: rawData[index].Timestamp,
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
        label: mapping[el],
      })),
  )
```

I have this error:

> Argument of type 'ZodLiteral[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [ZodTypeAny, ZodTypeAny, ...ZodTypeAny[]]'.
> Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.

How can I construct an array of Zod literals from an Record (mapping)?